# Updating large database with one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with 1,755,213 entries of post codes in CM23 5YF format. I want to change this to CM235YF just removing a space from them and score it in new column(Wardcode). 

**Table**

**Postcodes**  **Wardcode**,
 Here is what I'm using

Functions are

```
//*** Select * from uk_data
                function uk_pc_data($id){
                global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
                $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
                $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); ///*** for error handling 165000
                $STH = $DBH->query("SELECT * from uk_pc order by Postcode asc LIMIT $id, 50000");
                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $STH;
            }
            //*** Update Cat10 with Post code
                function uk_pc_update_wardcode(){
                global $host, $dbname, $user, $pass;
                $DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);
                $DBH->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                $STH = $DBH->prepare("update uk_pc SET 
                Wardcode   = :cat10
                WHERE Postcode = :Postcode
                ");

                $STH->bindValue(':Postcode' , $Postcode);
                $STH->bindValue(':cat10' , $cat10);

                return $STH;
            }
```

Using it in this way

```
$q = $_GET['id'];

$STH1 = uk_pc_data($q);
        while (($row = $STH1->fetch()) !== false) {
    $pc_o = change_text(' ', '', $row['Postcode']);

    $data_insert   = array(':cat10'=>$pc_o , ':Postcode'=>$row['Postcode']);
    $STH = uk_pc_update_wardcode();
    $STH->execute($data_insert);
    echo $pc_o .'<br>';

    }
```

Is there some easy way to change this. My script is working, but I wanna know is there any other way which i can use, only one script do it all ?

Comment: Ultra-inefficient... do NOT connect to the db every time you call those functions. That's like driving 5000 miles to pick a penny up off the ground at the destination. Connect **ONCE** outside your functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE postcodes SET new_column = REPLACE(old_column, ' ', '')
```

But you have to create new_column first.

Comment: There is no need for a completely new column. Just overwrite the values in the current column with the result from replace. But beware, when doing the update, it can take a very long time depending on the keys currently existing on the column. I would also suggest dropping the keys before doing the update and creating them again after.